# Issue in saving contact number into database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I'm giving correct contact number in the form field but it gets saved into database in some random digits,Why so?.i'm not using any encryption method!

Comment: Post your code, how is anyone meant to know what you are on about...

Comment: Is the number that's being stored `2147483647`?

Comment: problem solved ! it was problem with database column data-type.i changed it from "int" to "varchar".Now contact number got saved in correct form.

Comment: That's what I suspected.

Comment: yes @ceejayoz,exactly.

Comment: @ceejayoz,Why it isn't taking "int" type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INT` has a [max value](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/integer-types.html) of `2147483647` (or `214-748-3647`).

So, `555-555-5555` will get rewritten to the max it can store.

Phone numbers are NOT integers, so you shouldn't store them like that. All sorts of problems can happen - `055-555-5555` would be stored incorrectly as `55-555-5555`, `555-555-5555 x1234` can't be entered, etc.

Comment: Thank you @ceejayoz